# What is the meaning of RashmimAlA Mantras

Tags: mantras, goddess, vedic-gods

What are RashmimAlA Mantras? What's the importance of these mantras and 
Only Goddesses have these mantras ?

Comment: Btw note Rashmimala and RashimAlA refers to the same thing, the later is somewhat more perfect with regards to pronunciation with A standing for the long "a"  .. But for this particular answer I hv not used that scheme ...

Comment: Also I hv a hard copy of Nityotsava so i can quote from it .. the link that is given the answer is an overview of the text and not the full text..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rashmi Mala (Rashmi=Ray; Mala=Garland) Mantras are part of Sri Vidya worship. The Mantras are mentioned in the Parashurama Kalpa Sutra.

Details are also mentioned in the expository text [Nityotsava's](http://www.shivashakti.com/nityot.htm) 3rd chapter, a text which is based (chapter by chapter) on Kalpa Sutra itself.

After a disciple is initiated into Sri Vidya, he/she must perform daily some rituals without fail, and the reciting these Rashmimala is part of that daily ritual (Nitya Karma).

It is done immediately after waking up from sleep. That is, one is allowed to do the chanting on one's bed itself.

The daily ritual for Sri Vidya disciple has the following steps (as per Nityotsava):

> Ahnika Prakarana - Guru Dhyana (meditating on the Guru),
>  Pranasamjamanam (details omitted),
>  Chid
>   Vimarsha (details omitted),
>  Hrida Mulavritti (reciting the Mula mantra in heart),
>  **Rashmimala Smaranam (reciting or remembering the Rashmimala mantras)**,
>  Ajapa
>   Gayatri Bhavanam (details omitted),
>  Bhuprarthana to Mukha Prakshalanam (from praying to Earth to rinsing the mouth),
>   Snanavidhi (rules of bathing),
>  Sandhya Vidhi (rules for Sandhya) ... etc ..

So, Rashmi Mala recitation is a prerequisite (and a limb of the whole Sadhana) to be completed before the disciple embarks upon the main ritual, which is to worship Goddess Sri Lalita Mahatripura Sundari in the Sri Chakra.

Nityotsava's 3rd chapter, which is titled Sri Krama, states:

> Vakshyamanam rashmi mala mantramshcha ekavaram avartayeth |
>   Rashmisra gavartanam tu trai varnika vishayam ||
>
> The given Rasmi Mala mantras should now be chanted once. Reciting
>   these mantras are only prescribed for the Brahmins, Kshatriyas and
>   Vaishyas.

Then it gives the list of around 30 or so Mantras along with mentioning the limbs of the Mantras. Dhyana Slokas, which are to be recited before chanting the Mantras, are also given.

And, no, the Mantras are not only for the Goddesses, several Mantras are there which are for the Gods.

The list (of deity/mantra) is as follows:

> 1 Abhayankara Mantra (Abhayankaramantrasya Gritasmada rishih, Trishtup
>   chandah, Abhayankaro devata, tatprityarthe jape viniyogah)
>  2 Saura
>   mantra
>  3 Pranava (om)
>  4 Turiya Gayatri
>  5 Chakshus Mati
>   mantra
>  6 Viswa Vasu mantra
>  7 Pathividrudra
>  8 Tara mantra (
>   Tara mantrasya Matsya rishi, virat chandah, taramba devata, tat
>   prityarthe jape viniyogah )
>  9 Namatraya mantra (for Vishnu)
>  9
>   Mahaganapati
>  10 Shiva Shakti Atmaka mantra
>  11 Amrita Mrityunjaya
>   mantra (for Amritamrityunjaya Sadashiva)
>  12 Sruta Daharini Mantra
>   (for Brahma)
>  13 Matrika (for Saraswati)
>  14 Sri Hadi
>   Lopamudra
>  15 Bala Shadangam
>  16 Sampat Kari
>  17 Chanda
>   Yogeswari
>  18 Parashambhu Natha
>  19 Para Mantra
>  20 Bala
>   Tripura Sundari
>   21 Annapurneswari
>  22 Aswarudha
>  23 Sri
>   Vidya Guru Paduka
>  24 Laghu Shyama
>  25 Vagiswari
>  26 Nakuli
>   Vagiswari
>  27 Shyama Guru Paduka
>  28 Laghu Varahi
>  29 Swapna
>   Varahi
>  30 Tiraskarini
>  31 Varahi Guru Paduka
>  32 Sri Purti
>   Vidya
>  33 Mahapaduka Mantra.

So, these above 33 Mantras are known as the Rashmi Mala Mantras.

Comment: its awesome explanation!! Dhanyosmi  _/\_  _/\_

Comment: No problem mate .. btw whn u posted tht comment the match was on ..:D @SaMolPP